# How to extract p2sh from tx block

Tags: transactions, p2sh

I'm trying to extract p2sh addresses from blocks and I am not doing something correctly. What I have tried is:

```
    def decodep2sh(self, redeemscript):
        sha256 = hashlib.sha256(bytes.fromhex(redeemscript)).hexdigest()
        h = RIPEMD160.new()
        h.update(bytes.fromhex(sha256))
        final_address = base58check.b58encode(bytes.fromhex(h.hexdigest()))
        return final_address
```

Could anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you building this program from some example? If so can you provide the example.

Comment: What do you mean by an example?

Comment: Where did you get the instructions to decode a redeem script this way? Im not inferring its wrong, but if you are learning to do this from some source providing that context would be helpful.

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry for the confusion. No, I am doing this as part of my research at my university. I listening to blocks come in real time and trying to see if I can extract addresses.

Comment: I found this interesting article https://btcleak.com/2020/07/19/we-solved-a-p2sh-transaction-puzzle-and-redeemed-bitcoin/ which includes this python formula, perhaps it will work here.

>>> import binascii, hashlib, base58
>>> script = '51'
>>> base58.b58encode_check(binascii.unhexlify('05'+ hashlib.new('ripemd160', hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(script)).digest()).hexdigest())).decode()
'3MaB7QVq3k4pQx3BhsvEADgzQonLSBwMdj'

Comment: You should use existing Bitcoin libraries to do the parsing; there exist several in just Python alone. Based on other questions you're asking here, I infer you're basically trying to reverse engineer the transaction format. That'll take a long time, and will likely cause you to miss many edge cases even if you get it to work for most transactions.

Comment: @PieterWuille I appreciate what you're saying but my professor has explicitly told me I'm not allowed to rely on 3rd party libraries very much (so not at all).

Comment: @bitcoinluvr6969 So is this homework?

Comment: @PieterWuille No, sorry for the confusion. I work in a research lab.

Comment: That's a truly bizarre request from your professor then.